# Modify a sample in a mix using the original sample

Tags: filter

The song 'No Homo' by The Lonely Island samples 'Girls Can't Do What the Guys Do' by Betty Wright.

http://www.whosampled.com/sample/view/96863/The%20Lonely%20Island-No%20Homo%20Outro_Betty%20Wright-Girls%20Can%27t%20Do%20What%20the%20Guys%20Do/

In 'No Homo', the sample is lowered in pitch. I was able to raise the pitch to make it kind of sound like the original song. However, this obviously raises the pitch of the entire song. So my logic is to remove the sample from 'No Homo' and raise the pitch, then put it back in. Naively I thought I could cancel it out, but that obviously doesn't work because they're not the same waveforms.

Using Audacity, is there an easy way of changing the sample in 'No Homo' using the original song?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, if you knew exactly what they did to the sample, you could produce an inverse wave and recombine it with the mixed version in No Homo.  However in practice, since it is unlikely that you will be able to match the frequency shift exactly plus whatever other effects they may have applied (like compression), you are unlikely to be able to make an inverse wave that satisfactorily cancels out the original.